# It’s his manner I dislike, more than anything else. [comma]

Tags: commas, clefts

[ldoceonline.com](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/more):

> **(1)** *It’s his manner I dislike, more than anything else*.

As I understand, it's an it-cleft deriving from "*I dislike his manner more than anything else*." But I can't understand why need the comma after "*I dislike*". My version without it:

> **(2)** *It’s his manner I dislike more than anything else*.

So, what's the difference between (1) and (2)? Thanks!

Comment: With the comma: *I dislike his manner more than anything else **about him**.* Without the comma: *What I dislike more than anything else **at all** is **his manner**.* Although there is still room for ambiguity, that's how I would interpret it.

Comment: @Jason Bassford: Isn't it also correct to say, "It's his manner(s) that I dislike more than anything else."

Comment: @RamPillai Of course. They are both grammatical. But I wouldn't take them to mean the same thing. To me, the comma makes a significant change to the meaning. And I gave that interpretation in my first comment. If you *remove* the comma and want to keep the same meaning, then I'd say you need to add more information to the sentence: ***With respect to him***, *it's his manner I dislike more than anything else.* Otherwise, you're saying you dislike his manner more than death, taxes, or unpaid vacations …